# i want to create a table but bot able to create it

Tags: sql, hive, hql

i want to create a table in hive with NOT NULL property but i am not able to create it . it will says "ParseException line 1:44 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ) near ')' in create table statement".

i have tried with primary key option but it will give same error

```
create table AGENTS(agent_code varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
        agent_name varchar(40),
        working_area varchar(30),
        commission double(10,5),
        phone_no int(15),
        country varchar(25));
```

Comment: Side note : storing a phone number as an integer is a real bad idea. In some countries the leading zero(es) matter. And what of foreign nbrs like '+44 0000000000' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Hive supports `double` with scale and precision arguments.  And, I don't think there is a length for `int` Perhaps you intend numeric:

```
create table AGENTS (
   agent_code varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
    agent_name varchar(40),
    working_area varchar(30),
    commission decimal(10, 5),
    phone_no decimal(15),
    country varchar(25)
);
```

`NOT NULL` constraints are only enforced relatively recently, so that might also be a problem.

Comment: Hive supports `DECIMAL(p,s)` or just `DECIMAL` with (10,0) as default. Not _"numeric"_.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter . . . The more recent versions of Hive support `numeric` (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes) as do basically all other databases.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Hive version. Older versions of Hive do not support `NOT NULL` constraint like most databases. `NOT NULL` constraint was introduced from 3.0.0 version onwards.

Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16575